# How can I empty the ufw log file

Tags: log, ufw, purge

Is there a way I can purge (empty) the ufw log file (located in `/var/log/ufw.log`?

I tried `rm` but it didn't work.

I tried to stop ufw and delete the file but I couldn't do it.

Everybody talks about log level but nobody explains how to empty this file...

Answer (score 2):

As @muclux correctly points out, system files are usually removable only with administrator privileges; e.g. sudo. This command will remove the file:

```
sudo rm /var/log/ufw.log
```

Verify:

```
ls /var/log
```

Comment: After removing that file, the logging stops to work until I restart Rsyslog with `sudo service rsyslog restart`. To avoid that you could empty the file without removing it by doing `cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/log/ufw.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Using administrator privileges on the `tee` command as Jean Paul's comment pointed out will write over the file such that it becomes empty

```
cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/log/ufw.log
```

`sudo echo >/var/log/ufw.log` does not work, as the `sudo` only applies to the `echo` and not to the output redirection `>`